# Using custom ServiceAuthorizationManager WCF 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wif

I tried to add a Custom ServiceAuthorizationManager to my WCF service (.Net 4.5) by using the below configuration

#### Configuration

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="ServiceBehavior">    
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="TestWCFService.CustomAuthorizationManager TestWCFService" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Am getting an error as shown below

```
[InvalidOperationException: ID4039: A custom ServiceAuthorizationManager has been configured. Any custom ServiceAuthorizationManager must be derived from IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager.]
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +7934958
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ValidateDescription(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +381
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +306
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +90
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +175
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +740
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +125
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901*
```

IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager is a internal class located in  System.ServiceModel.Security.IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781704/unable-to-use-a-custom-serviceauthorizationmanager

Is it not supported in 4.5? Is there any alternative way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the new identity pipeline in 4.5 you must derive from ClaimsAuthorizationManager and wire it up using the system.identityModel configuration element.